# Left annihilator of $2\times2$ matrices.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

If we let $R$ be the ring of $2\times2$ complex matrices.
When is the left annihilator just equal to $\{0 \} $?
I see that if $A$ is invertible $\text{Ann}_{R} (A)$ is trivial since if $M \in \text{Ann}_R (A)$ then $MA =0 $ so we can just multiply on the right by $A^{-1} $ and so $M=0$.

But what about when $A$ is not invertible. Essentially I’m looking for zero divisors of the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: Hint: Since $A$ is not invertible, neither is $A^\top.$ So $A^{\top}$  has $0$ as an eigenvalue. Then there is a (non-zero) eigenvector $v$ so $A^{\top}v=0.$ So $v^{\top}A=0.$ Use $v^{\top}$ to construct $M.$ This works in any dimension.

Comment: So you can construct a matrix $M$ such that $MA=0$ just by taking the rows of $M$ to be a non trivial solution to $Av=0 $ which exists as $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: You only need one of the rows to be non-trivial, but yes. @Ben

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is not invertible, then consider a matrix $V$ associated to some non-zero linear map that is $0$ on $\operatorname{col}A$. Then, $VA=0$ and $V\ne 0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Isn't $\operatorname{col}A$ a standard notation?

Comment: You’re right, misread it.

Answer (score 0):

Every non-invertible matrix has a matrix which annihilates it. In general it can be constructed with the pseudo-inverse. In the $2\times2$ case the non-invertible:

\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b  \\
    c & d 
\end{bmatrix}

is annihilated by its adjoint:

\begin{bmatrix}
    d & -b  \\
    -c & a 
\end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is not invertible, then rank is 1 or $A=0$. If rank is 1, then columns are a multiple of each other. Then you can classify $2 \times 2$ non invertible matrices in the following way

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
a & ka \\
b & kb\end{bmatrix} \hspace{1cm} \text{or} \hspace{1cm} \begin{bmatrix} 
ka & a \\
kb & b\end{bmatrix} $$

Thus left annihilator can be

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
b & -a \\
lb & -la\end{bmatrix} \hspace{1cm} \text{or} \hspace{1cm} \begin{bmatrix} 
lb & -la \\
b & -a\end{bmatrix} $$